# Webpack dynamic import() and proxy caches

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a code similar to this that webpack handles perfectly:

```
import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk-name" */
  'my-package'
);
```

So that a chunk called "my-chunk-name" is generated which is fine.
The problem for us is that we have a proxy before our server that is used to cache file and this leads to a problem; after every release "my-chunk-name" can be changed but the proxy still serves the old version of the file for a while.

Is there any chance to add a timestamp to requested file so that it would be something like `my-chunk-name.js?_ts=1536219218007` ?
This would ensure that the proxy cache is eluded and a fresh copy of the file is served.

config file:

```
 output: { 
    path: outputPath, 
    filename: '[name].js', 
    chunkFilename: '[id].js'
 }
```

Comment: how is your config file? Specially the output section.

Comment: This is the output section of the webpack config file:


    output: {
        path: outputPath,
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
     },

Answer (score 3):

In order to accomplish that, use `[hash]`.

```
output: { 
    path: outputPath, 
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js', 
    chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].js'
 }
```

This hash is going to be different for every build, so your cash will be working totally fine when you update your files.

---

**Edit**

It is possible to have a unique identifier WITHOUT creating a new file each time, by replacing the chunkFilename with :

`[name].js?h=[contenthash]`

This way, you have a single file generated (as if you put `[name].js`), but during the network call, it adds the parameter `h`.

(ps: I can't comment)

Comment: This is a good solution but this will generate different files every building which is not a feasible solution my case (for many reasons).

Comment: [contenthash] changes only when there is a content change. Otherwise there is no other way to do that.

Comment: yes at every release it will build a new file; which as I said is correct but I need to avoid to generate new files at every build..

Comment: that is not possible, by any means with webpack. It will only always generate new files at every build.